# Adding legend to venn diagram

Tags: r, r-grid

I am using library `VennDiagram` to plot venn diagrams. But this function does not have a functionality to add legend and set names are displayed on or close to the sets themselves.

```
library(VennDiagram)
x <- list(c(1,2,3,4,5),c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
venn.diagram(x,filename="test.png",fill=c("#80b1d3","#b3de69"),
             category.names=c("A","B"),height=500,width=500,res=150)
```

[image: venn-diagram]

And with many sets, overplotting names is an issue and I would like to have a legend instead. The function is built on grid graphics and I have no idea how grid plotting works. But, I am attempting to add a legend anyway.

Looking into the venn.diagram function, I find that final plotted object is `grob.list` and it is a gList object and its plotted using `grid.draw()`.

```
png(filename = filename, height = height, width = width, 
    units = units, res = resolution)
grid.draw(grob.list)
dev.off()
```

I figured out that I could create a legend by modifying the `venn.diagram` function with the code below.

```
cols <- c("#80b1d3","#b3de69")
lg <- legendGrob(labels=category.names, pch=rep(19,length(category.names)),
                 gp=gpar(col=cols, fill="gray"),byrow=TRUE)
```

Draw the object `lg`

```
png(filename = filename, height = height, width = width, 
    units = units, res = resolution)
grid.draw(lg)
dev.off()
```

to get a legend

[image: legend]

How do I put the venn diagram (gList) and the legend (gTree,grob) together in a usable way? I am hoping to get something like base plot style:

[image: plot-with-legend]

or the ggplot style

[image: plit-with-legend]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue using the `VennDiagram` package and learn a bit of `grid` on the way:

#### Prepare diagram and legend

```r
library(VennDiagram)
x <- list(c(1,2,3,4,5),c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
diag <- venn.diagram(x,NULL,fill=c("#80b1d3","#b3de69"),
             category.names=c("A","B"),height=500,width=500,res=150)


cols <- c("#80b1d3","#b3de69")
lg <- legendGrob(labels=c("A","B"), pch=rep(19,length(c("A","B"))),
                 gp=gpar(col=cols, fill="gray"),
                 byrow=TRUE)
```

#### Transform the diagram to a gTree

(I'd love to find a better way if anyone knows one)

```r
library(gridExtra)

g <- gTree(children = gList(diag))
```

#### Plot the two `gTree`s side by side

```r
gridExtra::grid.arrange(g, lg, ncol = 2, widths = c(4,1))
```

[image]

#### Or one above the other

```r
grid.arrange(g, lg, nrow = 2, heights = c(4,1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are allowed to use other packages than `VennDiagram`, I suggest the following code using the `eulerr` package:

```
library(eulerr)

vd <- euler(c(A = 5, B = 3, "A&B" = 2))
plot(vd, counts = TRUE,lwd = 2,
     fill=c("#80b1d3","#b3de69"),
     opacity = .7,
     key = list( space= "right", columns=1))
```

with `key`  you define the legend location and appearance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution as well, but the venn diagram region is not square aspect ratio. And the legend is not spaced ideally.

```
library(gridGraphics)

png("test.png",height=600,width=600)
grab_grob <- function(){grid.echo();grid.grab()}
grid.draw(diag)
g <- grab_grob()
grid.arrange(g,lg,ncol=2,widths=grid::unit(c(0.7,0.3),"npc"))
dev.off()
```

[image: plot]